# An interesting geometric inequality from Japan. $a\sin A +b\sin B +c\sin C \ge 9r$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

This problem comes from a club-wide Mathematics Contest at Keio University, of which my friend was a participant in, he sent me this problem, the very last one on the test:

> In a triangle $\triangle ABC$, show that:
> $$a\sin A +b\sin B +c\sin C \ge 9r$$

Here, $A, B$ and $C$ are they vertices and angles of the triangle. $a,b$ and $c$ are the lengths opposite to these vertices respectively and $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circles.

According to him, this was the problem that stumped him. I attempted this problem in the following way, I think I got very close to proving it but I'm not sure if I can go further:

We know the following:

$$\Delta=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A$$

$$\sin A=\frac{2\Delta}{bc}$$

Similarly, we have:

$$\sin B=\frac{2\Delta}{ac}$$

$$\sin C=\frac{2\Delta}{ab}$$

We can write, $a\sin A +b\sin B+c\sin C$ as:

$$\frac{2a\Delta}{bc}+\frac{2b\Delta}{ac}+\frac{2c\Delta}{ab}$$

$$2\Delta(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab})$$

$$r(a+b+c)(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab})$$

Now, applying the AM-GM inequality here, we can get:

$$\frac{r(a+b+c)(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab})}{9}\ge r\sqrt[3]{abc}\sqrt[3]{(\frac{a}{bc})(\frac{b}{ac})(\frac{c}{ab})}$$

**EDIT**: After reinspecting my attempt, I can solve it:

$${r(a+b+c)(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab})}\ge 9r\sqrt[3]{abc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}}$$

$${r(a+b+c)(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab})}\ge 9r$$

This is how I did it. Is this attempt valid? Did I make any mistakes? And are there any alternative routes to prove this? Please share your answers!

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1887796p12869376

Comment: I must admit that the notation is not clear to me. From $\triangle ABC$ I would assume that $A, B, C$ are the vertices of the triangle. Are the same capital letters used for the angles? (This is not my area of expertise, so it might be obvious to others.)

Comment: That is absolutely correct. @MartinR

Comment: But what is $r$?

Comment: At a guess I would say $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle, or of the minimal circle in which the triangle is inscribed but without that one cannot really make a start.

Comment: @FShrike I have edited those details in

Comment: @samerivertwice Yes, $r$ represents the radius of the inscribed circle. I have edited in the details of the naming convention

Comment: Since $a \sin A + b \sin B + c \sin C = r \left(a+b+c \right) \left(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab} \right)$, cannot you substitute the expressions to generate the inquality that you are trying to prove.

Comment: I did, I proved it using that method. I'm trying to ask if this approach was valid, if I made any mistakes and if there are any alterative ways to do it @S.A.Lloyd

Comment: My apologies, I misread your last statement.  I believe that you methodology is correct and validd.